# MySQL group by query with multiple sums not using index, lagging on using filesort

Tags: mysql, group-by, database-performance, database-optimization, filesort

Given the following table ...

```
CREATE TABLE values_table (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  account_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  model varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ...
  value1 int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  value2 int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  value3 int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  value4 int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  ....
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2364641 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the following query...

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(value1) AS value1, SUM(value2) AS value2, SUM(value3) AS value3, SUM(value4) as value4
from values_table
where account_id = 10 and model = 'ModelName'
group by user_id;
```

....what fields should be added to an index and in which order to ensure that an execution won't end up `Using temporary; Using filesort;`?

I've tried adapting details described at http://mysqldba.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-pick-indexes-for-order-by-and.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html with no luck.

**Update**
I've tried `(account_id, model)`, `(account_id, model, user_id)`, `(account_id, model, user_id, value1, value2, value3, value4)`. None of them prevent the use of a temporary table and filesort.

Comment: Add an index for account_id and model. The order should not be relevant.

Comment: That did not eliminate the filesort.

I've tried (account_id, model), (account_id, model, user_id), (account_id, model, user_id, value1, value2, value3, value4).

None of them prevent the use of a temporary table and filesort.

Comment: add `INDEX user_id (user_id)`

Comment: `(account_id, model, user_id)` unless those conditions return big part of the table. You can append all the `valueX` columns to make the index "covering", but that should not be needed unless your table is really big.

Comment: @mscifo can you add results of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` when using the `(account_id, model, user_id)` one (or the even longer one)? that should tell us some more info - how many rows are in the table and how many of them have `account_id = 10 and model = 'ModelName'` ?

Comment: @mscifo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffdc7/1 check "View Execution Plan" it shows index is used

Comment: Ignore the temp/filesort; does the 3-column index run reasonably fast?

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that MySQL can only optimize `group by` with an index when all the columns are in the index.  And then, only a subset of these queries can be optimized.  Your question already points to documentation, but here is the more recent [version](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html).

You can reduce the volume of data with an index on `(account_id, model)`.  However, you might still have lots of matches and then MySQL gets finicky about indexes and `group by`.

There is a way to get MySQL to use indexes for aggregation.  If you only had one calculated column, then you could try:

```
select u.user_id,
       (select sum(v.value1)
        from values_table v
        where v.account_id = 10 and v.model = 'ModelName' and
              v.user_id = u.user_id
       ) as sum1
from (select distinct user_id
      from values_table
      where v.account_id = 10 and v.model = 'ModelName'
     ) u
group by u.user_id;
```

This should use an index on `values_table(account_id, model, user_id)` for the subquery in the `from`.  It should also use and index for the correlated subquery:  `values_table(user_id, account_id, model, value1)` is ideal.  However, you have to repeat this construct (and perhaps the optimal index) for each column in the output.  What is faster for one aggregated column may suffer if you have ten.

If this doesn't work, you then have fewer options:

- Decide that you really need a more highly restrictive `where` clause to reduce the volume of data.
- Use a trigger to maintain pre-aggregated data at the user level.